# Limit cycle for a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

> Consider the system
>   $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x (\lambda-x^2 + (1+\epsilon^2)y^2))+\omega y,~\frac{dy}{dt}=-\omega x + y (\lambda-x^2 + (1+\epsilon^2)y^2)).$$
>   Show that the system has a stable limit cycle for $\lambda, \epsilon >0.$

My approach: Setting the RHS of each equal to zero and adding the two terms yields:
$$(x^2+y^2)\lambda - x^2 (x^2+y^2)-(1+\epsilon^2)(x^2+y^2)y^2=0.$$
Using polar coordinates $x=r \cos \theta,~y=r \sin \theta,$ we get
$$r^2 \cdot (\lambda - r^2 \cos^2 \theta - (1+\epsilon^2) r^2 \sin^2 \theta)=0,$$
which gives 
$$r=0,~r=\pm \frac{ \sqrt{\lambda}}{\sqrt{(1+\epsilon^2 \sin^2 \theta)}}.$$
............................................................................................

As one of the comments suggested, I tried setting the right hand sides of each equal to zero.

$$x (\lambda-x^2 + (1+\epsilon^2)y^2))+\omega y=0,~-\omega x + x (\lambda-x^2 + (1+\epsilon^2)y^2))=0.$$

I tried method of elimination to solve for $x$ and $y,$ but wasn't successful. 
I still don't know how can this be any simpler than what I did before. 
I'm still stuck in this problem. Can someone please explain me from this how can I proved the desired conclusion. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you show this for $\varepsilon = 0$?

Comment: @HansEngler, Usually we find the critical points, plug into the linearized-system and find the eigen-values and then determine the stability. Here  I'm struggling to use the method.

Comment: that will not give you existence of a limit cycle, unless you can show there is a Hopf bifurcation. Even then you will usually only get an existence result for $\lambda$ close to the bifurcation parameter.

Comment: I see. If you can, please help me in solving this. Thanks.

Comment: "Setting the RHS of each equal to zero and adding the two terms" Since this is not useful to solve the exercise, please cite a similar simpler setting where you can show there is a limit cycle and/or the results at your disposal to do so in general. (Note also that turning to polar coordinates in the computation you tried is not useful either, and is actually making things worse.)

Comment: Actually it would, but this is at best a peripheral aspect so I suggest to concentrate on the main part of my comment.

Comment: Could the second equation be $y'=-\omega x+y(\cdots)$?

Comment: Great, see my answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In polar coordinates the equations are
$$
r'=r(\lambda-r^2\cos^2\theta-(1+\epsilon^2)r^2\sin^2\theta), \quad \theta'=-\omega.
$$
For $\omega>0$ the second equation implies that the only equilibrium is the origin. Now, for $r$ very small $r'>0$, while for $r$ very large we have
$$
r'=r(\lambda-r^2-\epsilon^2r^2\sin^2\theta)<0.
$$
Hence, it follows from the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem that there is a periodic orbit. Its stability is also the desired one.